# Creating a header that becomes fixed after going out of view?

Tags: html, css

Whats the best way to transition a standard header into a fixed one as it leaves the 'view-able area'?

Cant seem to find a good example of it but what happens is:

- Scroll down
- Header transition into fixed, full width.

Comment: Google "affix" or "affix header" Bootstrap affix is a good example. Here's a fiddle, one of the first hits on a google search: http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/df8tb/

Comment: I'll take a look, what about making it transition smoothly?

Comment: For smoothness, you might use CSS3 transitions when it changes the width. Most fixed navs just "pop" to the top when you hit a certain scroll point. I've not seen one do anything with animations. But still, I could envision transitions working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code will add a class of fixed if the top of the view-able area is greater than 412 px. Adjust this to match the position of the top of your header.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = 412;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('.header').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });
    });
```

The CSS

```
.fixed {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1;
    top:0
}
```

z-index so it will float over other fixed elements, you may have to increase the integer if you have other elements with z-index. And obviously top just indicates that its fixed to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can easily be achieved with JQuery.

I also took the initiative to add some animation, making it more appealing.

First you add a basic html body:

```
<body>
    <div id="mymenu"></div>
</body>
```

After that you set a basic css (the "html, css" is only there for the demo):

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#mymenu{
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:green;
    z-index:1
}
```

And then the JQuery:
It first store the original values, measure the offset from top then animate when it passes the threshold. When you go back it retakes his original position.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //declare variable relative to menu height and store the original width
            menuheight = $("#mymenu").height() + $("#mymenu").offset().top;
            menuwidth = $("#mymenu").width();
            menumargintop = $("#mymenu").css("marginTop");

            //start the analysis on scroll
            $(document).scroll(function(){

                //offset at the time of scroll
                var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
                var totalmenuoffset = offset-menuheight;


                if(totalmenuoffset > -200){ //when scroll over the set offset
                    //use stop to remove delay and animate to be way cooler 
                    $("#mymenu").stop().animate({ width : "100%", left: "0", right: "0", marginTop: "0px"}, 700);
                    $("#mymenu").css("position", "fixed");
                }
                else{ //or when returned to normal 
                    //use stop to remove delay and animate to be way cooler 
                    $("#mymenu").stop().animate({ width : menuwidth, left: "0", right: "0", marginTop: menumargintop}, 700);
                    $("#mymenu").css("position", "relative");
                }   
            })
        })

    </script>
```